# Test Complete/Execute 8 won't RefreshMappingInfo unless it's done through COM

Tags: ruby, testcomplete

I am running a test script in TestComplete v8. The object graph in memory gets out of date (as a dialog has appeared).

I run the following VBScript code

```
Sys.Process("iexplore").RefreshMappingInfo()
```

And I get the following error message...

```
Unable to find the object RefreshMappingInfo. See Additional Information for details.

The object with the specified attributes does not exist.

Possible causes of the error
```

This error relates to TC interpreting the method call as an attempt to find a control.

What is really odd.. If I connect to TC8 via COM and execute the same code, it works fine. 
So in ruby:

```
require 'win32ole'
tc = WIN32OLE.connect("TestComplete.TestCompleteApplication.8")
integration = tc.integration
Sys = integration.GetObjectByName("Sys")
puts Sys.Process("iexplore").Page("http://localhost:50563/x.aspx") _
  .Form("form1").Panel("silverlightControlHost").Object(0).UIAObject("Popup").Exists
' This returns false

Sys.Process("iexplore").RefreshMappingInfo()
' No error raised

puts Sys.Process("iexplore").Page("http://localhost:50563/x.aspx") _
  .Form("form1").Panel("silverlightControlHost").Object(0).UIAObject("Popup").Exists
' returns true
```

Why doesn't this work during a test? 
How do I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TestComplete has three object trees:

1. The **Sys** tree which can be found in the Object Browser panel and
   contains all application objects.
2. The **NameMapping** tree which contains all the mapping names.
3. The **Aliases** tree which is used when tests are recorded and which
   can be flexibly modified by a tester.

Objects in the **Aliases** tree reference objects in the NameMapping tree and objects in the later are referencing objects in the **Sys** tree. The **RefreshMappingInfo** method is used to refresh these references stored in objects of the **NameMapping** tree to objects in the **Sys** tree. So, the method exists only for objects from the **NameMapping** and **Aliases** trees.

In your code, you work with an object in the **Sys** tree: *Sys.Process("iexplore")*. You get an error since objects from the **Sys** tree does not have the **RefreshMappingInfo** method. You need either call the **Refresh** method or try working with an object from the **NameMapping** or **Aliases** tree. For example:

- *Sys.Process("iexplore").Refresh()*
- *Aliases.IExplore.RefreshMappingInfo()*

Comment: Sys.Refresh sometimes doesn't work. What would force a refresh of the Sys tree?

Comment: COM - Hard to say, perhaps a different exception tracking mechanism. The only way to refresh an object from the Sys tree is to call the Refresh method. If it does not work, the problem is in something else.

Comment: Contact SmartBear Support team in order to get assistance - http://support.smartbear.com/message/?prod=TestComplete